# Angular Material: cards align to center

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am learning Angular and I have creatred a serious of Angular `Cards` with `Angular Material`:

```
<div fxFlex="25%" fxFlex.xs="100%" fxFlex.sm="33%" *ngFor="let num of [1,2,3]">
    <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4 clickable" (click)="doStuff(num)">
       ...
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

[image]

The cards sticks to the left of the page. I would like to align the cards horizontaly so I tried to add a wrapper DIV element but this unfortunately dose not work:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center none">
     <div ... *ngFor="let num of [1,2,3]">
         ...
     </div>
</div>
```

What is the proper way to implement this alignment?

Comment: That should work. I think there is a problem on width of the parent div. Can you pls check that? It seems the parent div which contains cards does not set as the full width of the screen.

Comment: I  had multiple `<div fxLayout>` and that causes the issu. Thx.